# How transform array ob objects to object with next view?

Tags: javascript

How can i transform data to next view??? I get array with array of object and I need to get an object with the value of each of these objects and the key true

```
let content = [

      [
        {
          "dataType": "TEXT",
          "name": "Username",
          "value": "grey07"
        },
        {
          "dataType": "DOUBLE",
          "name": " Identifier",
          "value": 2070
        },
        {
          "dataType": "TEXT",
          "name": "First name",
          "value": "Laura"
        },
        {
          "dataType": "TEXT",
          "name": "Last name",
          "value": "Grey"
        }
      ],
    [
        {
          "dataType": "TEXT",
          "name": "Username",
          "value": "grey07"
        },
        {
          "dataType": "DOUBLE",
          "name": " Identifier",
          "value": 2070
        },
        {
          "dataType": "TEXT",
          "name": "First name",
          "value": "Laura"
        },
        {
          "dataType": "TEXT",
          "name": "Last name",
          "value": "Grey"
        }
      ]
]


let head =content[0].reduce((acm, el) => {
for (let key of Object.keys(el)) {
  acm[key] = true;
}
return acm;
}, {});
```

console.log(head)//should be

[object Object] {
'Username':true,
'First name': true,
'Identifier': true,
"Last name": true
}

not necessary to use reduce

Answer (score 0):

You only need to set the value of the `name` property to true in the object.

```js
let content = [

      [
        {
          "dataType": "TEXT",
          "name": "Username",
          "value": "grey07"
        },
        {
          "dataType": "DOUBLE",
          "name": " Identifier",
          "value": 2070
        },
        {
          "dataType": "TEXT",
          "name": "First name",
          "value": "Laura"
        },
        {
          "dataType": "TEXT",
          "name": "Last name",
          "value": "Grey"
        }
      ]
];
const head = content[0].reduce((acc,{name})=>(acc[name]=true, acc), {});
console.log(head);
```

Answer (score 0):

You if you only need `name` only, then you just have to target that only

```js
let head = content[0].reduce((acm, el) => ({...acm, [el.name]: true}), {})
```

---

Full code

```js
let content = [
  [
    {
      dataType: "TEXT",
      name: "Username",
      value: "grey07",
    },
    {
      dataType: "DOUBLE",
      name: " Identifier",
      value: 2070,
    },
    {
      dataType: "TEXT",
      name: "First name",
      value: "Laura",
    },
    {
      dataType: "TEXT",
      name: "Last name",
      value: "Grey",
    },
  ],
  [
    {
      dataType: "TEXT",
      name: "Username",
      value: "grey07",
    },
    {
      dataType: "DOUBLE",
      name: " Identifier",
      value: 2070,
    },
    {
      dataType: "TEXT",
      name: "First name",
      value: "Laura",
    },
    {
      dataType: "TEXT",
      name: "Last name",
      value: "Grey",
    },
  ],
]

let head = content[0].reduce((acm, el) => ({...acm, [el.name]: true}), {})

console.log(head)
```